# Issue occurred with Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am facing this below illustrated issue and I don't know Why this error occurred:

[image]

Please help on the issue.

Comment: It was not able to find js/zepto.min.js check whether the file exists. Try updating composer packages

Comment: I did composer update , still same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting vendor folder and update composer